# How to use glyphicons in this code

Tags: php, codeigniter

This code in pic below:

**Image:**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it deppends on form_submit($data);. But you can make data like this, so you can insert the $data['html'] inside the botton.

```
$data = array(
    'class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-myblock',
    'name' => 'signin',
    'value' => 'Sign In',
    'html'=>'<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>'
);
?>

<?php echo form_submit($data); ?>
```

Comment: With my pleasure @Youhan